# Implement semaphores using the monitor concept

Tags: java, multithreading, operating-system, semaphore, monitor

I am trying to implement semaphores using the monitor concept in Java. I.e Java class that implements a weak counting semaphore (using methods init, signal and wait)

Can someone tell me if this class is correct (if not what is the problem):

```
class MyMonitor
{
    int counter = 0;

    //init
    public MyMonitor( int init )
    {
        counter = init;
    }

    //Signal
    public synchronized void S()
    {
        counter++;
        notify();
    }

    //Wait
    public synchronized void W()
    {
        if( counter == 0 )
        {
            try
            {
                wait();
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e) { }
        }

        counter--;
    }
}
```

If this is correct, could someone give me an idea of how I can test the class.

Answer (score 1):

It should be like this (with `while`, not `if`):

```
class YourMonitor
{
    int counter = 0;

    //init
    public MyMonitor( int init )
    {
        counter = init;
    }

    //Signal
    public synchronized void S()
    {
        counter++;
        notifyAll();
    }

    //Wait
    public synchronized void W()  throws InterruptedException
    {
        while ( counter <= 0 )
        {
            wait();
        }

        counter--;
    }
}
```

How to test:

```
public class TestYourSemaphore
{
    private static final int CNT = 100000;

    private int x = 0;
    private YourSemaphore s = new YourSemaphore();

    public void run() throws InterruptedException
    {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new MyRunnable());

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();


        // Verify, that the X has correct value
        if (x != 3 * CNT)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Race condition error!");
        }
        System.out.println("Finished");
    }

    private class MyRunnable implements Runnable
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < CNT; i++)
            {
                //un-comment to use Semaphores
                //s.enter();
                x = x + 1;
                //s.leave();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Without semaphore, the Exception is thrown all the time (almost).
- With suggested semaphore, the Exception is not thrown.
- With your semaphore, the Exception is sometimes thrown (but not so often as without semaphores).

The problem with your semaphore is:

1. thread 1 has a lock
2. thread 2 and thread 3 are `wait()`ing
3. thread 1 calls `notifyAll()`
4. thread 2 and 3 simultaneously enter the critical section, which is bad :)

Comment: I do not understand, why you replaced notify() by notifyAll(). Without notifyAll() you do not have the problem, that you describe, because you wake up exactly 1 thread. Even if you consider the spurious wakeups described in another comment here I see no reason for notifyAll()

Answer (score 0):

Well the only problem that I see is this part:

```
    if( counter == 0 )
    {
        try
        {
            wait();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException e) { }
    }

    counter--;
```

If the thread gets interrupted while waiting, it will simply exit the `if` statement, decrement the counter below 0 and then your semaphore system goes horribly wrong, since now nobody will be forced to wait because `counter` is less than 0.

You should probably replace the `if` with a `while`, just in case.

Comment: The other reason to use `while` is 'spurious weakup'.

Answer (score -1):

Just a question: Why don't you use the java standard?
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html ?